# P-adic integers

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Show that $\frac{2}{p-1}$ is a $p$-adic integer and find its p-adic expansion.  P-adic numbers really make little sense to me so any help explaining what to do and why would be really appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots$.

Comment: If they make little sense to you, get the book "p-Adic Analysis Compared with Real" by Svetlana Katok.  That is, if you have had real analysis and that made sense, then this book will help you understand p-adic numbers.  It's at an advanced undergraduate level.  I've read it twice.  It's only about 150 pages total and it's only $23 on Amazon (in the U.S.).  I have heard "p-adic Numbers: An Introduction" by Gouvea is good too but I have never read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $p=2$ then your expression is just equal to $2\in\Bbb Z$.

If $p$ is odd then numerator and denominator are prime to $p$, thus $p$-adic units. The quotient of $p$-adic units is a $p$-adic unit. Recall that a $p$-adic unit is an invertible element in the ring $\Bbb Z_p$ and can be recognized as those $p$-adic integers having a non-zero "costant" term in their $p$-adic expansion.

In order to get the $p$-adic expansion of $\frac2{p-1}$ just rewrite it as $-2\frac1{1-p}$ and apply Chris Eagle's hint.

Comment: Right thanks for that everyone.  After a bit of playing around I get that $a_0=(p-2)$  $ a_i=(p-3)$ for $i=1,2,...$ so $(p-2)+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(p-3)p^i$ is the expansion.  Does that sound right?